# Why pass data into an AJAX request 'success' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Recently I started learning jQuery and AJAX and am a little confused with AJAX requests.

For practice, I am making a very basic TodoApp using **Node**, **jQuery** and **Bootstrap**. I was really getting confused with all these GET and POST requests. I finally understood those properly but I am unable to understand why we need to send data back through the 'success' function after making a POST request. I did however, remove the data param from the success function and tried to do it that way but it gave me an error, but after refreshing the page I could see that my entry had been entered.

EDIT: This is about the the POST request which happens when the user adds an item.

I have listed all the files I think are related to this question and also the related dependencies.

Dependencies: Express, Handlebars(the templating engine I'm using), Bootstrap, jQuery.

- app.js contains code for the actual express app.
- main.js contains the ajax requests.
- todoController.js contains the handlers to the requests.
- todo.hbs is the handlebars file which gets rendered when the user visits '/todo'

app.js
```

```
var express = require('express')
var hbs = require('express-handlebars').create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials'
})
var todoController = require('./controllers/todoController')

var app = express()

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

todoController(app)

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('...' + app.get('port') + '...')
})
```

```

main.js(inside the public folder)
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jumbotron').hide().fadeIn(500)

    $('#add-button').on('click', function(){
        var todo = $('#todo-input').val()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/todo',
            data: {item: todo},
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload()
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('something went wrong.')
            }
        })
    })

    $('.todos-list').on('click', function(){
        var item = $(this).val()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/todo/' + item,
            success: function(){
                location.reload()
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```

todoController.js
```

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})

var data = [
    {
        item: 'Get shit.'
    },
    {
        item: 'Get milk.'
    }
]

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
        res.render('todo', {title: 'TodoApp', todos: data})
    })

    app.post('/todo', urlEncodedParser, function(req, res){
        data.push(req.body)
        res.json(data)
    })

    app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res){
        data = data.filter(function(todo){
            return todo.item.replace(/ g/, '-') !== req.params.item
        })
        res.json(data)
    })
}
```

```

todo.hbs
```

```
<input type="text" id="todo-input"/>
<button type="submit" id="add-button">Add Item</button>
<ul class="todos">
    {{#each todos}}
        <li class="todos-list">{{this.item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

```

Comment: You dont need to pass data back to the client. However you then would not notice any connection problems / server errors

Answer (score 1):

The client-server paradigm works that clients make requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc) to the server, which receives it, perform same operations (generally involving a database) and based on the request type, the server sends a response to the client. 
In GET requests, the client asks for a specific value and the returned value is mandatory.
In POST requests, generally the client ask to the server to store same data into database and, since any error may occurs on the server side, it is important to response with an acknowledge or alternatively, with the error occurred.

This is the main reason for which the client needs in any case a response from the server before considering the request completely executed.